# Review and Feedback on my Prototype Button Module for Breadboard

Tags: pcb-design, breadboard, schematic, review

I'm working on creating a button module that can be placed on a breadboard. I've designed the schematic for it and am considering converting it into a PCB soon. You can find the images of the module and schematic below.

[image: [Attach the schematic image]]

[image: [Attach the module image]]

Being my first design, I'm primarily looking for insights on the following:

Functionality: Will this design work as intended?
Redundancies: Are there any redundant components or connections that can be omitted?
Improvements: Any suggestions on how the design can be made more efficient?
Potential Issues: Are there any potential issues you foresee with this design when converting it into a PCB?
It's worth noting that, at this stage, I'm not overly concerned about the efficiency or potential over-complexities in the design. My primary goal is to understand and learn from any mistakes or improvements you might suggest.

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: mechanically, you need to add some support on the side opposite from your pin header. We cannot review your PCB layout, because you have not shown us any PCB layout so far.

Comment: It would help if you said what does the button module do, what is the purpose and how it should work, and why specifically these chips are used. Then we can say if it does it or not, and whether or not it has useless parts. At least it will not work at all due to a schematic mistake of chips being left unpowered.

Comment: `Will this design work as intended?` ... that depends on what you intend the module to do

Answer (score 3):

I can't really advise much – I don't know your intended use case. I don't think your approach is *universally* useful, but it might fulfil some *specific* need!

There's no PCB layout that you gave us so far to review, so we can't give any feedback on that.

- Your VCC / VDD connection is wrong. The decoupling capacitor goes to ground, not in series. This won't power on the ICs.
- I don't see how the ICs you choose would fit on this board at all, assuming the red line is a planned outline. These are SSOP-20! So they are a bit more than three 2.5mm Pin header rows wide. You don't have that space.
- Can't put the ICs on the bottom beneath the switches well, as these are through-hole.
- I don't really see why you would need the debouncing at all here. You're reading the button state with an IO extender. So, your host system would simply wait some milliseconds before it queries the IO extender, done!
- Speaking of which, if you just want to read a bunch of switches via SPI, a Parallel-to-Serial shift register does that for a couple of cents, and with none of the brains you need to put in.

Comment: My goal is to grasp electronics. I chose this project to navigate all development steps. I'm crafting a button module with i2c that manages debounce. I realize my chip choices might seem much, but I'm learning. This module will work with a breadboard and later other boards, using a ready-made module approach. I haven't designed the PCB yet but pondered a PCB Support Pillar for stability. Considering a double-sided board with SMD parts. Thanks for pointing out the capacitor issue. If I fix it, will my circuit work fully?

Comment: But if you're trying to learn electronics, then why the debounce IC? That's a complicated integrated circuit (running something very close to a small computer inside, actually, a minimally programmable clocked finite state machine) that you will find very rarely in real-world applications, because usually, debouncing is simply either *not* done on the button side, or done by simple analog means – so, actual elecronics that you *could* grasp, and understand the workings of!

Comment: This IC is meant to make the lives of engineers easier that need to debounce large, long-ringing buttons in very noisy environments, like, say, large switches on industrial welding machines, something like that. Something where the time to design this one circuit is much much more expensive than placing two resistors and a capacitor! Something that someone else than the designer has to solder, too :)  Maybe follow the simple analog design from [this](https://hackaday.com/2015/12/09/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-i/) article (two resistors and a capacitor), or

Comment: … the nicely buffering one, which also has a bit of hysteresis through the Schmitt-Trigger inputs (doesn't have to be a 74HC14; can really be any gate with a Schmitt-trigger input, or even cooler, build your own Schmitt Trigger with a comparator and two resistors.)

Answer (score 3):

If we only focus on if it will work or have problems, there are only two small but critical mistakes.

The power supply VCC is not connected to the chips, and the MCP23008 reset needs a pull-up as it must not be left floating.

Otherwise, the chips seem to be used by the book. And the schematics are  drawn mostly according to common rules so it is rather clear and easy to understand.

As for improvements, the pinheader could benefit from the reset signal, because if you imagine this product being connected to an MCU, and maybe the MCU reboots in the middle of communicating with the IO expander chip, it is possible that SDA is stuck low and the MCU refuses to communicate on the bus. It is easier to send a reset pulse to the chip when MCU boots, than to start controlling power to the IO expander or executing a special sequence on the bus to exit the stuck situation.

So just fix the VCC to chips and add a pull-up to reset and you can enjoy the product.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even looking at the electronics yet, but I really recommend considering the overall design.

As Marcus points out in comments, when you hit a button, you'll really be torqueing your connector.  This may damage the board, or simply make the connector pull out.

There are other problems as well.  Deployed as pictured, the breadboard isn't particularly useful, with only two rows showing, and no place for IC's.  If you mount it on the bottom half of the board, the breadboard is more useful, but your mechanical torque problems may get (much) worse.

The way to figure out what will go wrong is mostly to picture the device in use, and imagine yourself using it (That's basically why Justme is asking for your use scenario in comments under your question).  Then, spend real time thinking about what you can do to make your design malfunction.  At the start, you think about how you can make your design *work*, but at some point, you flip the tables, enter "sabotage" mode, and start thinking about what you would need to do to make your device *fail*, and tweak your design so the failures can't happen.

You might opt to not put all your buttons in a single row, you may decide to add some sort of feet or something to help you deal with your torque issues, or maybe another 0.1" header that does nothing electrically, just for mechanical support.

Comment: I like this angle a lot! I also forgot make clear in my answer that I can't really advise much, because I don't know what it's for.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller -- I teach design, and I time this lesson pretty carefully in the course, because entering an Failure Mode Analysis mode prematurely during design can quash innovation, but it's pretty good to take a stab at it before physically prototyping (at least for expensive, time consuming prototypes).